# When is the latest time to do Hoshanot on Sukkot?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, zemanim, sukkot, hoshanos

I was wondering if Hoshanot can be done all day (like lulav and Hallel) or if it can only be done by a certain time.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly Halchically speaking,given that there is no Bracha involved the Hoshanot are פיוטים and there will be no transgression of an aveira no matter when they are said.

But we do find 3 different minhagim of the correct positioning of the Hoshanot

The first two are based on an argument of when the kohanim were מקיף the  מזבח (which is the reason for the mintage of saying Hoshanot)

- Rishonim(סידור רש"י, מחזור ויטרי ועוד) -

learn that they did so after the Korban Mussaf, hence they hold that the Hoshanot should be said after Mussaf.

- סידר רב סעדיה גאון -

holds that the kohanim would be מקיף after shachris (similar to nettles lulav) that's why he holds that Hoshanot should be said after leining (completion of shachris services)

- Mekubalim אר"י ז"ל -

  (שער הכוונות דרושי חג הסוכות דרוש ה וכף החיים סי’ תרס סעיף ד) - for mystical reason it should be done after hallel

For further reference see אוצר מפרשי ההושענות שע"י מכון ירושלים pages 49-54